# ASP.NET session is NULL despite a IRequireSessionState/IReadOnlySessionState handler?

Tags: asp.net, session

While looking into [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587859/asp-net-gone-fubar-on-a-production-machine) I met a peculiar situation.

Within the Global.asax method I have the following code:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)) // No session - no validation.
        return;
    DoSomething();
}
```

The `DoSomething()` method call throws a `NullReferenceException` and it is simple enough that the only place it could do that was if `HttpContext.Current.Session` was null.

How can this be?

Answer (score 1):

At that time `HttpContext.Current.Session` may well be null.  The event is firing at the point where the session is **being** aquired there is no guarantee that at this point it has **been** aquired.  One reason you might hook this event is because you are providing a custom module to implement your own Session object.  It would be here that such a custom module would set the Session.

If you want to use the Session object you should be using the `PostAquireRequestState` event.

Answer (score 0):

In this method the Session object is not yet constructed so it is inaccessible. Try to do the work in any method that is executed after this method. Maybe
Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute or look at this page to see the order of execution of methods in global.asax file 
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5771721.html

The remaining events deal with application requests, and they're triggered in the following order:

```
* Application_BeginRequest
* Application_AuthenticateRequest
* Application_AuthorizeRequest
* Application_ResolveRequestCache
* Application_AcquireRequestState
* Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute
* Application_PreSendRequestHeaders
* Application_PreSendRequestContent
* <<code is executed>>
* Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute
* Application_ReleaseRequestState
* Application_UpdateRequestCache
* Application_EndRequest
```

Comment: Funny, because it has always worked both on my and many other machines.

Comment: Are you using AJAX call? If it is the case it might be a source of problem

Comment: How is an AJAX call any different for a server? O_o